# Box-Shadow is not working on hover in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css

I am trying to apply box-shadow on a div on hover in mozilla, chrome , IE10 it is working fine but in IE 8 text is also getting shaded i am attaching here image of IE8

[image]

and in mozilla it is working fine here is image [image]

Here is my css for both

```
.span3:hover {
   box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
   -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    border-radius:3px;
 }


.lt-ie9 .span3:hover {
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    border-radius:3px;
    zoom: 1;
      filter:
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);
}
```

Please explain me where i am doing mistake. i tried many links like css3pie.com etc but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Box Shadow Compatibility versions](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

It is not Supported in IE8

[To Enable CSS box-shadow for IE](http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow)

[How to Simulate CSS3 box-shadow in IE6-8 Without JavaScript](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/)

or Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which emulates [some CSS3 properties](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

IE 8 not support css3 directly

Comment: That is what i have suggested, if you come up with same answer you can upvote as per community norms.